# How to deploy maven artifacts from maven build server to Artifactory server in AWS AMI instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, artifactory

**Context**: Maven-Server is an AMI instance, Artifactory is also on another AMI instance.
Trying to deploy maven artifacts from Maven-server AMI to Artifactory AMI.

**Problem**: Unable to deploy artifacts due to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/).

**Stacktrace**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:sprhava:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.
boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.4 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for reposit
ories: [central (http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/maven-libs-release, default, releases), snapshots (http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/maven-libs-snapshot, default, releases+snapshots)] and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM.
```

**settings.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd" xmlns
    ="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <servers>
        <server>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>Helloadmin123</password>
          <id>central</id>
        </server>
        <server>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>Helloadmin123</password>
          <id>snapshots</id>
        </server>
      </servers>
      <profiles>
        <profile>
      <mirrors>
            <mirror>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/sprhava-libs-release</url>
                <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            </mirror>
      </mirrors> 
    
      <mirrors>
            <mirror>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/sprhava-libs-snapshot</url>
                <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            </mirror>
      </mirrors> 
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </snapshots>
              <id>central</id>
              <name>sprhava-libs-release</name>
              <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/sprhava-libs-release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
              <snapshots />
              <id>snapshots</id>
              <name>sprhava-libs-snapshot</name>
              <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/sprhava-libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
          </repositories>
          <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </snapshots>
              <id>central</id>
              <name>sprhava-libs-release</name>
              <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/sprhava-libs-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
              <snapshots />
              <id>snapshots</id>
              <name>sprhava-libs-snapshot</name>
              <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/sprhava-libs-snapshot</url>
            </pluginRepository>
          </pluginRepositories>
          <id>artifactory</id>
        </profile>
      </profiles>
      <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
      </activeProfile>
    </settings>
```

**pom.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>maven</name>
    <description>DevOps CI/CD project </description>
    <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>ip-ec2-ipaddress.compute.internal-releases</name>
            <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddress:8082/artifactory/maven-libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

From last four days, I am trying to fix this, tried checking Artifactory Security Group:

[Artifactory-SG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et99u.png)

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: settings.xml is using the same maven build artifacts to deploy on artifactory

Comment: which `ide` you can use

Comment: I guess this problem is due to the Maven 3.8.x default blocking of http repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Put the mirror with blocking=false in the settings.xml file. Also I was missing the appropriate mirrorof Id.

**Soution**

```
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
        <mirror>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddr:8082/artifactory/maven-libs-release</url>
    <blocked>false</blocked>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>

    <mirror>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <url>http://ec2-public-ipaddr:8082/artifactory/maven-libs-snapshot</url>
    <blocked>false</blocked>
    <mirrorOf>snapshots</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
      </mirrors>
  <profiles>
```